# UIScrollView with Size Classes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

do you guys know what good tutorial to learn about this?

when I was using XCode 5 I can set the scene's height manually in storyboard. after I finished customize the scene I set the scene's height to default height. but I can't do that with size classes

I've been searching for this tutorial on google, but most of them disable size classes and auto layout. I want to learn about it.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can do the same in size classes using freeform option as you used to do in xcode 5, bt one thing you have to consider is the any*any is for iphone 6 size, but for specific devices you hav to make use of specific size classes interface.

Comment: Is it possible to design a scrollview that runs on different devices with differing widths?

Comment: yes its possible, if you are using constraints, then set scrollview width, and leading and trailing constraints to the superview or the parent view.

Comment: It seemed that I needed to specify the size of a view using the freeform option. If I set the width to the correct value for an iPhone then it is too small for an iPad since the value is not set for a size class, and vice versa. Is it necessary to specify a freeform size to fit an iPad and then calculate the constraints to fit the iPhone. I can't remember the exact details but this did not appear to work when I attempted to do this. I should have added that I was attempting to embed a UITableView into the scrollview.